# Is it possible to assign a new value to a returned pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a form that I'm creating and to simplify things, I'm trying to create a form field mapper to an object. As such, I create the following dictionary:

```
self.fieldPropertyMapper = @{
@(CompanyFieldName):self.company,
@(CompanyFieldDescription):self.company.description,
@(CompanyFieldWebsite):self.company.website,
@(CompanyFieldTwitter):self.company.twitter,
@(CompanyFieldAddress):self.company.address,
@(CompanyFieldAddress2):self.company.address2,
@(CompanyFieldCity):self.company.city,
@(CompanyFieldState):self.company.state,
@(CompanyFieldZipcode):self.company.zipcode,
@(CompanyFieldPhone):self.company.phone
};
```

The keys here are members of the `CompanyFieldType` enum.

My goal here is to later in my form to assign a value to the returned pointer. Here's what I mean: when a text field in one of my forms stops editing, I'm looking to set the value. Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CompanyFieldType fieldType = [self fieldTypeForTag:textField.tag];
    // Set the value of the respective company property 
    // In theory it would be something like:
    // self.fieldPropertyMapper[@(fieldType)] = textField.text;
}
```

I'm assuming there's a way to assign by reference but I'm forgetting how to do this. (Is it using the `&` symbol or `**`?) I don't remember. Help appreciated! If I'm messing up my terminology, feel free to let me know.

Comment: It sounds like I may need to use NSMapTable. Any insight would be useful though!

Comment: If your keys are `NSNumber`-wrapped enum values (as it seems they are), the code you commented out should work fine. `NSDictionary` key lookup is based on object equality, not pointer equality. Since `NSNumber`'s `-isEqual:` method would return `YES` for two different objects that box the same underlying primitive value, this code should work.

Comment: @indragie unfortunately this doesn't work because the code I commented out would attempt to assign a value to the dictionary key (which happens to be immutable) versus a value to the returned pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want to do. That is to say, there is no pointer magic that will do what you want.

You can get essentially the same effect, though, with key-value coding. Instead of storing the result of accessing the property (e.g. `self.company.website`), instead you want to just store the key path to the value you're interested in as a string — e.g. `@"company.website"`. Then you can do like so:

```
[self setValue:textField.text forKey:self.fieldPropertyMapper[textField.tag]];
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm going to test it out now and will get back momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSMapTable` initialized with `NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory` for the keys and `NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory` for the values. Then you could store the addresses of your iVars backing your properties as the values in the table.

```
[self.mapTable setObject:&_company forKey:@(CompanyFieldName)];
```

Haven't tested this but this should get you started.